# Can't be Integrate Twitter Plugin in cordova iOs

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova-3

I'm developing social application using cordova 3.1.0 using 4.6 xcode.and my os x version is 10.8.5.
Now,I'm trying to implementing twitter plugin for my application.i got the source from this :[LINK](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms)

I've gone thru step by step.I also integrated child-browser framework.
Now.i got this Error:

```
2013-10-17 12:15:17.141 FinalTwitter[12484:c07] ERROR: Method 'showWebPage:' not defined in Plugin 'ChildBrowser'
2013-10-17 12:15:17.141 FinalTwitter[12484:c07] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "ChildBrowser383058088",
  "ChildBrowser",
  "showWebPage",
  [
    "https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/oauth\/authorize?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true",
    {
      "showLocationBar" : true,
      "locationBarAlign" : "top"
    }
  ]
]
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not called ChildBrowser anymore but [inAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) ;) You should update the code I believe.